# UIWebView accepts normal NSStrings but not a NSString from an object

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview

So I have an object called 'theList', this contains a load of information about a student, one element is a url to an image of their work online. I am using a webview to display that image using the code:

```
    NSString *urlAddress2 = theList.imageofwork; 
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress2]; 
    NSURLRequest *requestObj2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2]; 
    [workWeb loadRequest:requestObj2];
```

This doesnt work, but when I change 'theList.imageofwork' (which contains 'http://google.com' I should say, while I test this) to '@"http://google.com"' it works absolutely fine.

Though I need this to be able to draw from 'theList' as the view is general and should change depending on the student that you select. So my question is what am I doing wrong or is there some other way that I should be going about displaying images?

Also, within theList.h, imageofwork is declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageofwork;
```

and in theList.m I have:

```
@synthesize imageofwork;
```

I should also mention that I am relatively new to xcode and this is my first post here!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put in some logging around the variables as they change and repost? Feel free to set `theList.imageofwork = @"http://google.com"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the documentation of the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class more carefully.

Here is what you should need: [loadHTMLString:baseURL:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a)

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question

Comment: There's no reason he can't use the way he's using

Comment: From what I understood he is loading an HTML string from an NSString. At least this is what I understood and that's why i suggested using the loadHTMLString method

Comment: If the `imageofwork` is not being set correctly to begin with, it won't matter if he's using a UIWebView or not. What he's doing should work just fine.

Comment: I have tried the method that you're suggesting, and it still doesn't work, instead of loading the page it just displays the URL that I would like it to load

Comment: I am also checking what theList.imageofwork is set to using NSLog and it is displaying what it should be, so I assume that it is being set correctly

Comment: Ok if it's an actual URL then you are using the correct method, I thought it was an HTML string. So yes, you should make sure that imageofwork is an NSString and it has the correct value. Set a breakpoint and print the value of theList.imageofwork and see what it says.

Comment: Setup a breakpoint in [workWeb loadRequest:requestObj2]; and in GDB or lldb do this: po url2 and write down to us here what it says

Comment: ahh, I assume that this is the problem, when checking it it appears as "\nhttp://google.com", now to work out where that is \n is coming from... Thanks for your help